# Google Blogger API - 403 Forbidden while using Google Blogger API

Tags: google-api, blogger

It was working fine till a while ago but after few requests I started getting the error saying

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I even generated the API key from the google console and then added the key like following to the post url

?key= but still getting the same error.

Is there a daily free quota for making Post / Put requests ? Thanks.

Comment: I have already done that and even tried service account , client id and even api key but non worked. I am actually generating the access token using Oauth 2 playground and then using that access token in my post request.

Comment: It worked for approx 50 requests a while back and then all of sudden starting throwing this error.

Comment: Just checked the Blogger Developer Group and realized that they have a default quota of 50 post requests a day which can be increased on request. I have requested them to increase the quota for me.

Comment: nice answer and the problem solved :)